# How to run my React app in Apache?

Tags: apache, reactjs, webpack, bundle

Currently I am using React with Webpack. I want to execute React without running "npm start". So after lot of research I found that I can run in production without using "npm start" just by using Webpack to create a "bundle.js".

So far I have created my "bundle.js" and it runs fine in my Node server.

I now want to test this in Apache server.

The "bundle.js" file is created in "dist" along with "index.html". When I am trying to run in Apache server, it does not include the React code.

So my question is: how do I run my React app in Apache?

This is my webpack-config.js

```
 const path = require("path");
 const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
 module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/js/root.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "js/main.js"
  },
 devServer: {
  contentBase: "./dist"
 },
 module: {
 rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader"
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "html-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
 },
 plugins: [
   new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
   template: "./src/index.html",
   filename: "./index.html"
 })
]
};
```

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0- 
  beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  <title>How to set up React, Webpack, and Babel</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
            <p>Create a new article</p>
            <div id="root-container">
                <!-- form -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <script src="../dist/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside my dist folder it created 2 files,
 index.html and main.js.

Comment: Where are you placing the index.html file ? Does it have bundle.js reference in it ?

Comment: are you create react app with `create-react-app` ? or using custom setup your own webpack?

Comment: It will help us help you more easier if we see the code. But just a shot in the dark, check your `<script src='bundle.js'></script>` path in `index.html`

Comment: I have used custom setup. I have not used create-react-app.

Comment: I will update my code now

Answer (score 1):

I faced your problem before, I tried to host compiled React code on Apache, but then the script does not seems to be loaded properly, so I did some change in `index.html` to use `relative path` instead of `absolute path`.

*Look at [this article](https://www.linux.com/blog/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix) to understand more about path.*

### Before

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.f73baec9.js"></script> 
...
```

### After

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/main.f73baec9.js"></script> 
...
```

Just an extra dot will do.

#### Explantion

If you host it on Apache, and you did not use relative path, the server will try to look for your script in the server root instead. So, unless you host your compiled React code directly in the server root, you will need to use relative path.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have included like this only . When i run this server I am able to see file is included but, its not displaying only html content not react code.

Comment: I have included like this only . When i run this server I am able to see file is included but, its displaying only html content not react code.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your situation.